# Why is Android Studio telling me to use getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar()?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-studio

Just adding a very simple help activity (simply displays a block of HTML text from a resource file), to a very simple test app, in this new-fangled Android Studio 0.8.6 beta and I'm getting the following warning, with no reason / justification offered:

[image: Should use getSupportActionBar instead of ActionBar name]

Does anyone know why?

Also is there any documentation, as Android Studio offers none and can't find anything specific on the android site.

If there is a justification for the warning, can someone please point me at a complete example,as the class as it is is almost completely generic / per most of the examples around e.g.

```
public class HelpActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.action_help));

    TextView helpText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.help_text);
    helpText.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.help_markup)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getSupportActionBar()` is the same as `getActionBar()`, but comes from the Android Support library.

Android Studio is recommending you switch to `getSupportActionBar()` because, if you did not, your application would not be backwards-compatible with previous versions of Android.

It is a good practice to use the Android support library wherever possible if you intend to be backwards-compatible - otherwise your application may crash on older platforms. If you don't intend to  be backwards-compatible, then you are free to ignore this warning.

For more information, take a look at the [docs for `ActionBarActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html), in which it tells you:

> `getSupportActionBar()`: Support library version of `getActionBar`().

Comment: Thanks, is there anything official (other than obscure warnings popping up in the new tool) about using the support class? I ask as the documentation and examples on the droid site still use the original.

Comment: @arober11 A good place to start is, honestly, [the Support Library page](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) from dev.android - most of this honestly just concerns how layouts are organized and processed. Most of the time, Android Studio will warn you, but if you're doing something big with fragments and layouts, it's always a good idea to check.

Comment: There is a bug in AS 0.8.9 (current at this time), even if your manifest specifies API 15+, it wants you to use getSupportActionBar which is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for noting it's a bug. I already wondered why it should be good practice to use SupportActionBar if you configured to use API level > 10 (16 in in my case).
Android programming is so messy sometimes.