# does getSupportActionBar().hide() surport android 4.0 and below?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I hid my actionbar in my android app with the following code

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
```

I wish to know if this will hide the action bar for android phones with android 4.0 and below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes . From document :

```
The ActionBar APIs were first added in Android 3.0 (API level 11) but they are also available in the Support Library for compatibility with Android 2.1 (API level 7) and above.
```

You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Answer (score 0):

Reading from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597253/why-is-android-studio-telling-me-to-use-getsupportactionbar-instead-of-getacti). ***Yes***, it will hide Action Bar for phones below android 4.0

> getSupportActionBar() is the same as getActionBar(), but comes from
>   the Android Support library.Android Studio is recommending you switch
>   to getSupportActionBar() because, if you did not, your application
>   would not be backwards-compatible with previous versions of Android.

To make sure your action bar is hidden, the easiest way is to have your theme extend from `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` (or the light variant).